# Android: Access to AssetManager inside a singleton class?

Tags: android, android-assets

I have a singleton class which manages data and database handling of my application. I create a sqlite3 database with default values and kept it in the asset directory. In one of my APIs of this class I have made a check that if DB doesn't exist in /data/data//my.db  then copy it from asset directory to this location.

Given my class is singleton and doesn't inherit from UI classes, Is this possible that I can write this API in my current setup or I have to rethink some alternate design?

```
Class DBHandler {

// singleton class

public void initDatabase() {

   File dbFile = new File("/data/data/<mypackage/a.db>");
   if (dbFile.exists()) {
    return;
   }

   //copy database from asset directory

   //How to do this here?????

}

};
```

I want to know is this possible??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pass a `Context` reference to `initDatabase()`, then you can use its methods to acceess files and databases in your app's private directory.

Comment: Did you meant to declare a context in the current class or pass it from some activity class??

Comment: And also if I have to pass the context from some Activity then is it possible to pass the context as reference: The below link shows parameters in java is always happen by call by value: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference

Comment: Pass it from your activity. You don't need to change it, and it _is_ a  reference, so there is no issue.